# If statement to review start date column, compare to columns headers and if there is a match, paste value in corresponding cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script sorting the sheet on edit already and I would like to add an `if` statement to it: if the date in column C matches a date in columns L:NL then paste the value in corresponding row E in the corresponding row/column.

**Excel Versions:**

```
if(L$1=(indirect("C"&row())),(indirect("E"&row())),"")
if(M$1=(indirect("C"&row())),(indirect("E"&row())),"")
if(N$1=(indirect("C"&row())),(indirect("E"&row())),"")
```

and so on....

**Columns:**

- Column C3:3 has the start dates of meetings
- Column E3:3 has the subject of the meetings
- Columns L1:NL1 each has a unique date that changes based on what is in Column C.

**Current Script:**

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')  
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:NL");

  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}]);

  var start = sheet.getRange("C3:C").getValue();
  var day = sheet.getRange("L1:NL").getValue();

  if(start[1][0]== day)
    // Here is where I get lost
}
```

Example [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFMKvGsi7Omn1PL5XFR1RLiCo1Z3fFDTATJzziMlJts/edit?usp=sharing) incase it helps.

Update:
Here is my current script that I am still working on

```
function sortLabel() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rangesToClear = sheet.getRange("L3:NL");
  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows()
  var lastCol = sheet.getMaxColumns()

  rangesToClear.clearContent();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:K");
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}]);

  for (var i = 3; i < lastRow; i++) {
    var meetingSubject = sheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var startDay = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();  
    var day = sheet.getRange(1, 12, 1, lastCol).getValues();

    if (startDay = day) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 12).setValue(meetingSubject);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your ranges include more than 1 cell you should be using getValues() which returns an array.

Comment: Along with what @Cooper mentioned, your `day` range is going to be an exponentially growing number of cells.  Your range is `L1:NL`, which means start at `L1`, and end at `NL(bottom row)`.  I think you meant to compare dates that are in the first row, so `L1:NL1`.  THEN you need to use nested `for` statements to cycle through the `start` and `day` arrays so that your `if` statement can function.  The variables you use for the `for` statements will go into the first set of brackets [ ] in the `if` statement for both variables.  Then you need to tell it what to do when the `if` is true.

Comment: @RonKloberdanz I am not sure where you see my range being L1:NL. I do have a clear var of `rangesToClear` of L3:NL because every time the data re-sorts I will need to paste the new values into the correct corresponding cells. 
I thought I was comparing L1:NL1 by the var day = `sheet.getRange(1, 12, 1, lastCol).getValues()`. Also can you help me understand what you mean by my if statements. I am new and really trying to learn.

Comment: You have definitely made it closer with the updated script.  First point:  I would move `var day = sheet.getRange(1, 12, 1, lastCol).getValues();` outside of (above) the `for` loop.  You don't need to re-create the array for every row iteration.  Second point:  My original comment was about moving through the data and comparing different variables.  You have the first part with the `for` statement to cycle through the different rows.  Now you need a second `for` statement to cycle through the `day` array that you created, so that you can compare every date column to each row.

Comment: Then add the second variable to the `setValue` statement to place it in the correct column:  `sheet.getRange(i, j).setValue(meetingSubject);`.  **NOTE**:  You MAY need to change your dates to strings to compare them properly.  Date variables can have time data associated and that could prevent equality in a comparison.  Just something to watch for if you aren't getting output.